# optimization word problem in calculus

Tags: calculus, optimization

You are asked to build an open cylindrical can (i.e. no top) that will hold $665.5$ cubic inches. To do this, you will cut its bottom from a square of metal and form its curved side by bending a rectangular sheet of metal.

[image]

**(a)** Express the total amount of material required for the square and the rectangle in terms of $r$.

I just need a hind nothing more, do I have to add the area of the rectangle with the area of the square?

Comment: "do I have to add the Area of the rectangle with the area of the square?" => Yes.

Comment: Hint: $\pi r^2 h=665.5$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas So the Area of the rectangle will be 1331/r. What about the square, why there is a circle in it?

Comment: The square has area $4r^2$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas and what will be the unit of the equation if we take the derivative ?

Comment: @AndréNicolas is it cubic inches ?

Comment: In spite of the opinion of physicists, it is not necessarily useful to worry about units here. But if you really want units, the derivatives' unit is the inch.

Comment: minimize $4r^2+2\pi rh$. Relation b/w $r$ and $h$ is from the volume required.